# C++ with a math library like GSL, LAPACK, or CBLAS performance vs C++ with Rinside with an R function?

Tags: c++, r, lapack, gsl, rinside

Has anyone ever done a straight up apple to apple comparison between:

1. A C++ application calling an algorithm done in a R functions using RInside
2. A C++ application calling the equivelant algorithm but using a one of the math libraries like GSL, LAPACK, or CBLAS?

I am trying to get benchmarks which would be faster. I am also interested in what kind of parallalzation/multithreading designs that might make the calculate faster within C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from startup costs for initializing R which you only get in case 1) by your study design, the results *should be identical as R itself uses the exactly same BLAS AND LAPACK libraries* if built correctly.

I have a to-be updated package / vignette which proposes a benchmarking framework for exactly these questions as the issue is so easy to misunderstand -- see the [CRAN page for gcbd](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gcbd) as well as [the corresponding pdf vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gcbd/vignettes/gcbd.pdf).

If you build R differently (eg statically, or with its own BLAS / LAPACK sources), then you are  getting different results but you are also not making an apples-to-apples comparison.

Comment: Hey Dirk, what is the proper way as you suggest to ensure to get best performance with RInside?

Comment: Install a fast BLAS / LAPACK library. But "usually" your overall performance will not be bounded by linear algebra performance.  Also consider (Rcpp)Eigen as an alternative to BLAS / LAPACK.